Are rough and smooth boundaries (or primal and dual) always Z stabilisers and X stabilisers?
I've been going through a lot of literature on surface codes and lattice surgery, and I keep running into the issue of different papers, at least to me, changing their definition of rough and smooth (primal and dual), without explicity stating whether the surface bounday is given by X or Z stabilisers.
For example, in Surface code quantum computing by lattice surgery and Surface codes: Towards practical large-scale quantum computation, they both specify the rough(primal) boundary as $Z$ and the smooth(dual) boundary as $X$. However, in A Game of Surface Codes: Large-Scale Quantum Computing with Lattice Surgery, in the section A Surface-code qubits and lattice-surgery operations, smooth(dual) boundaries are gives as $Z$ and rough(primal) as $X$.

But then later on in this same section, they are swapped again, with the rough now being given as $Z$ and smooth as $X$.
So which is it? It seems to me like this shouldn't be interchangeable, but maybe I am getting confused as the concepts of dual and primal also come up in syndrome graphs as well, along with correlation surfaces, and my definitions are getting mixed up.

This is like worrying that, because paper A drew its X stabilizers in red while paper B drew its Z stabilizers in red, paper A is inconsistent with paper B. It can be annoying that two papers pick different color conventions. It means you to do some recoloring when combining them. But it's not a showstopping problem.
In your case your "colors" are "X stabilizer drawn as face" and "X stabilizer drawn as node". Switching these "colors" doesn't change the underlying operations being described. It just changes how you're drawing them. You just sometimes have to do some "recoloring" when combining papers (or, sometimes, different diagrams from the same paper tsk tsk).
(There is also the overlying "color convention" of using X and Z stabilizers, instead of Y and Z. Or X and Y. Or $(X-Y)/\sqrt{2}$ and $(X+Y)/\sqrt{2}$. None of these choices really affect anything. What matters is that they are consistent across the whole computation, because what truly matters is how things interlock.)

I agree it isn't an issue when they specify, like in the Game of surface codes paper, what the smooth and rough boundaries represent. I do find it's an issue when just rough/ smooth or primal/dual are used, and no reference is given to actually determining to what opeators those boundaries have support on. Hence me trying to determine if indeed there is an agreed upon language.

@GaussStrife If they don't specify which basis they mean, you can pick whichever one works for your current use. In some ways that's the most convenient.

Provided they anticommute with eachother, correct?

@GaussStrife Right.
